# Implementing VisualSearch.js using jQuery-Ajax, REST API and Neo4j GraphDB

Tags: jquery, rest, neo4j

I am trying to implement [**VisualSearch.js**](http://documentcloud.github.io/visualsearch/) using ***jQuery-Ajax***, ***REST API*** and ***Neo4j GraphDB*** at back-end. I have gone through the post at this [**link**](http://maxdemarzi.com/2013/07/03/the-last-mile/), which has implemented the same using ***Ruby***.

Here is my my code.

```
var visualSearch;      

$(document).ready(function() {
var facets=[];
$.ajax("/facets", {
    type:"GET",
    dataType:"json",
    success:function (res) {
        facets = res;
    }
});

      visualSearch = VS.init({
      container  : $('#search_box_container'),
      query      : '',
      showFacets : true,
      unquotable : [
        'text',
        'account',
        'filter',
        'access'
      ],
      callbacks  : {
        search : function(query, searchCollection) {
          var $query = $('#search_query');
          var count = searchCollection.size();
      $query.stop().animate({opacity : 1}, {duration: 300, queue: false});
          $query.html('<span class="raquo">&raquo;</span> You searched for: ' +
                  '<b>' + (query || '<i>nothing</i>') + '</b>. ' +
                  '(' + count + ' node' + (count==1 ? '' : 's') + ')');
          clearTimeout(window.queryHideDelay);
          window.queryHideDelay = setTimeout(function() {
            $query.animate({
              opacity : 0
            }, {
              duration: 1000,
              queue: false
            });
          }, 2000);
        },

    valueMatches : function(facet, searchTerm, callback) {
    alert(facet)        
    var restServerURL = "http://localhost:7474/db/data";
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: restServerURL,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
        data: { /*Query goes here.*/ },
            success: function( data, xhr, textStatus ) {
                alert(data.self);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR);  
            alert(textStatus);                  
            alert(errorThrown);
            },
            complete: function() {
                alert("Address of new node: " + data.self);
            }
    });     
    },
        facetMatches : function(callback) {
        if(visualSearch.searchBox.value() != "") {
        $.ajax("/connected_facets", {
                 type:"POST",
                 dataType:"json",
                 data: {/*Query goes here.*/},
                 success:function (res) {
                    callback(res);
                }
        }); 
        } else { 
                callback(facets);
            }
         }
      }
    });
  });
```

It would be a great help if anyone could point out the problem. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: What is the actual question? What's the behavior of your code?  I can't readily run this without writing some server-side handlers for the ajax calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the problem is in the valueMatches. You don't use a callback passed to this function. If you dig VisualSearch sources ([visualsearch.js:696](https://github.com/documentcloud/visualsearch/blob/efc3c6c350c23706f45bab717578ff56c114d7d7/build/visualsearch.js#L696)) you'll see that this callback (lines 701-727 in the code) provides filtered suggestion data from valueMatches to the jQuery autocomplete, that the VisualSearch is built on (see [visualsearch.js:1043](https://github.com/documentcloud/visualsearch/blob/efc3c6c350c23706f45bab717578ff56c114d7d7/build/visualsearch.js#L1043)).

So in your case it will look like:

```
        valueMatches: function(facet, searchTerm, callback) {
            var restServerURL = "http://localhost:7474/db/data";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: restServerURL,
                dataType: "json",
                data: {facet: facet, query: searchTerm},
                success: function(data) {
                    callback(data);
                }
            });
        },
```

This code assumes that your application at the url above receives **facet** and **query** POST-variables and serves an answer as an array in JSON, so it is passed directly to the callback (see *success* option).

The same with the facetMatches. But if you have a fixed set of facets you can even pass them directly in code:

```
        facetMatches: function(callback) {
            callback([
                {label: 'facet1', category: 'cat1'},
                {label: 'facet2', category: 'cat1'},
                {label: 'facet3', category: 'cat2'},
                {label: 'facet4', category: 'cat2'},
                {label: 'facet5', category: 'cat2'}
            ]);
        },
```